# Wordpress - Divide average by 2 decimal places

Tags: wordpress, count

I have code that gives me the average of certain number which is fine however, it's giving me quite a long number e.g. 4.8571428571429

Is it possible to get it down to 2 decimal places e.g. 4.85

Hope it makes sense, my code so far is below

```
<?php // Get total number of posts in custom post type
    $count_testimonials = wp_count_posts('testimonial');
    $total_testimonials = $count_testimonials->publish;                                            
    $new_average = ($add) / ($total_testimonials);
    echo $new_average;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this: `number_format((float)$new_average, 2, '.', '')`

```
<?php
$count_testimonials = wp_count_posts('testimonial');
$total_testimonials = $count_testimonials->publish;                                            
$new_average = ($add) / ($total_testimonials);
$new_average;
echo number_format((float)$new_average, 2, '.', '');
?>
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks.